# vba max value of group of values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table formated like this:

```
A           B     C
==         ==    ==
groupID1  comp1   1
groupID2  comp2   2
groupID1  comp3   3
```

what I want to achieve is to have the max value of the group added to the line in column D. 
Following excel formula in column D gives the response I want:

```
=INDEX(C:C;SUMPRODUCT(MAX((A:A=A2)*ROW(A:A))))
```

unfortunately my laptop cannot handle this on a list of 50k lines. can somebody help me out with vba to make it more performant?

thx
siech

Comment: You're performing that on millions of lines, not 50k, as you're using entire columns. Use only the range you wish to calculate - if that range will change then look at named ranges or use a proper table.

Comment: Hi, thx for your input. I tried limiting the range but with no real performance improvement: =INDEX($U$2:$U$60000;SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($A$2:$A$60000=A2)*ROW($A$2:$A$60000))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it doesn't use formulas so its definitely faster.
This `Sub` will fill the Max for that group in column D.

```
Sub FillGroupsMax()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'stop screen updating makes vba perform better

    Set last = Range("A:A").Find("*", Cells(1, 1), searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
    'last cell with value in column A

    Dim groupsArray As Variant
    'array with all group infomation
    Dim groupsSeen As Variant
    'array with group infomation already seen

    groupsArray = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(last.Row, 3))
    'collect all the information on the Sheet into an array
    'Improves performance by not visiting the sheet

    For dRow = 1 To last.Row
    'for each of the rows

        'check if group as already been seen
        If inArrayValue(Cells(dRow, 1).value, groupsSeen) > 0 Then
            'if it has been seen/calculated attribute value
            Cells(dRow, 4).value = inArrayValue(Cells(dRow, 1).value, groupsSeen)
        Else
            'if it hasn't been seen then find max
            Cells(dRow, 4).value = getMax(Cells(dRow, 1).value, groupsArray)

            'array construction from empty
            If IsEmpty(groupsSeen) Then
                ReDim groupsSeen(0)
                groupsSeen(0) = Array(Cells(dRow, 1).value, Cells(dRow, 4).value)
                'attribute value to array
            Else
                ReDim Preserve groupsSeen(0 To UBound(groupsSeen) + 1)
                groupsSeen(UBound(groupsSeen)) = Array(Cells(dRow, 1).value, Cells(dRow, 4).value)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    'reactivate Screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Function getMax(group As String, groupsArray As Variant) As Double

    'for each in array
    For n = 1 To UBound(groupsArray)
        'if its the same group the Max we seen so far the record
        If groupsArray(n, 1) = group And groupsArray(n, 3) > maxSoFar Then
            maxSoFar = groupsArray(n, 3)
        End If
    Next

    'set function value
    getMax = maxSoFar
End Function

Function inArrayValue(group As String, groupsSeen As Variant) As Double

    'set function value
    inArrayValue = 0
    'if array is empty then exit
    If IsEmpty(groupsSeen) Then Exit Function

    'for each in array
    For n = 0 To UBound(groupsSeen)
        'if we find the group
        If groupsSeen(n)(0) = group Then
            'set function value to the Max value already seen
            inArrayValue = groupsSeen(n)(1)
            'exit function earlier
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Comment: This works great! thx, would never have figured this out. many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following, this will add the formula to the range, and the formula will only look in the give range with data, so instead of looking at the full Column A it will only look until the last row with data:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    'get the last row with data on Column A

    Set Rng = ws.Range("D1:D" & LastRow) 'set the range where you want your formula
    Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(R1C3:R" & LastRow & "C3,SUMPRODUCT(MAX((R1C1:R" & LastRow & "C1=RC[-3])*ROW(R1C1:R" & LastRow & "C1))))""
    'add the formula to the range
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

inspired but your amazing help I made some minor changes that could maybe be useful for others. Comments on my changes also most welcome.

- added worksheet dim;
- added dynamic column count (last column will be updated with max of pre-last column);
- exclude first row (header);
- save updates in array and only write last column to sheet at the end; (performance increase was only minor, would have expected more);

  ```
  Sub FillGroupsMax()
      Dim lColumn As Long
      Dim sht As Worksheet
      Dim groupsArray As Variant    'array with all group infomation
      Dim groupsSeen As Variant    'array with group infomation already seen

      Application.ScreenUpdating = False    'stop screen updating makes vba perform better

      Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("import")
      Set last = sht.Range("A:A").Find("*", Cells(1, 1), searchdirection:=xlPrevious)    'last cell with value in column A
      lColumn = sht.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

      groupsArray = sht.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(last.Row, lColumn))
      'collect all the information on the Sheet into an array
      'Improves performance by not visiting the sheet

      For dRow = 2 To last.Row    'for each of the rows skipping header

          'check if group as already been seen
          If inArrayValue(Cells(dRow, 1).Value, groupsSeen) > 0 Then
              'if it has been seen/calculated attribute value
              'Cells(dRow, 4).Value = inArrayValue(Cells(dRow, 1).Value, groupsSeen)
              groupsArray(dRow, lColumn) = inArrayValue(Cells(dRow, 1).Value, groupsSeen)
          Else
              'if it hasn't been seen then find max
              'Cells(dRow, 4).Value = getMax(Cells(dRow, 1).Value, groupsArray)
              groupsArray(dRow, lColumn) = getMax(Cells(dRow, 1).Value, groupsArray, lColumn)

              'array construction from empty
              If IsEmpty(groupsSeen) Then
                  ReDim groupsSeen(0)
                  'groupsSeen(0) = Array(Cells(dRow, 1).Value, Cells(dRow, 4).Value)
                  groupsSeen(0) = Array(groupsArray(dRow, 1), groupsArray(dRow, lColumn))
                  'attribute value to array
              Else
                  ReDim Preserve groupsSeen(0 To UBound(groupsSeen) + 1)
                  groupsSeen(UBound(groupsSeen)) = Array(groupsArray(dRow, 1), groupsArray(dRow, lColumn))
              End If
          End If
      Next

  sht.Range(Cells(1, lColumn), Cells(last.Row, lColumn)).Value = Application.Index(groupsArray, , lColumn)
      'reactivate Screen updating
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True

  End Sub

  Function getMax(group As String, groupsArray As Variant, lColumn As Long) As Double

      'for each in array
      For n = 1 To UBound(groupsArray)
          'if its the same group the Max we seen so far the record
          If groupsArray(n, 1) = group And groupsArray(n, lColumn - 1) > maxSoFar Then
              maxSoFar = groupsArray(n, lColumn - 1)
          End If
      Next

      'set function value
      getMax = maxSoFar
  End Function

  Function inArrayValue(group As String, groupsSeen As Variant) As Double

      'set function value
      inArrayValue = 0
      'if array is empty then exit
      If IsEmpty(groupsSeen) Then Exit Function

      'for each in array
      For n = 0 To UBound(groupsSeen)
          'if we find the group
          If groupsSeen(n)(0) = group Then
              'set function value to the Max value already seen
              inArrayValue = groupsSeen(n)(1)
              'exit function earlier
              Exit Function
          End If
      Next

  End Function
  ```