# How to extract percentile from 2D array in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, multidimensional-array, percentile

I would like to extract the 80th percentile from the second column in MyArray below. Is this possible in Excel VBA?

I have tried with Worksheetfunction.Index below although this gives error "Argument not optional".

```
Sub test()

    Dim MyArray(1 To 2, 1 To 100)

    For f = 1 To 100
    
        MyArray(1, f) = f
        MyArray(2, f) = f * 3

    Next f

    Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.Percentile(Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(MyArray, 0.80))

End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: You want to slice the array:  see here for options and a discussion on which is the quickest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48598247/slice-array-to-use-index-on-larger-than-65000

Comment: @ Scott Craner That works for me. Great, thanks!

Comment: @ Scott Craner Shall I delete my question since my question has a similar question?

Comment: @user2165379 You're good to leave it here, it's been marked as a dupe so people who stumble upon this can follow the link.